# getting the height of the div within another div

Tags: jquery

I have a div which i need to get the height of. It is inside a div and it has several divs inside of it. They're both inside a similar div structure. I made a js fiddle to illustrate my problem and with what i have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/K3dx5/

So basically I need to get the height of the first div when a link is clicked(400px), also on the second link(200px).

> ```
> <div class="wrapper">
>     <div class="one">  <!--I need to get the height of this div -->
>     <div class="NotThisone">
>        <div class="No">
>     <a class="anchor">ONE</a>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> <div class="two"> <!--I need to get the height of this div -->
>     <div class="NotThistwo">
>         <div class="No">
>     <a class="anchor">TWO</a>
>         </div>
>     </div>    
> </div>
> ```
>
> ​

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `closest()` method, with a selector:

```
$('.anchor').click(function() {
    var height = $(this).closest('.wrapper > div[class]').height();
    console.log(height);
});​
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K3dx5/3/).

References:

- `closest()`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first , use

```
var x = $(this).closest('.one').height();
```

For the second, use

```
var x = $(this).closest('.two').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong.

```
var x = $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('height');
```

The div in question is three levels up from the anchor so you need to use three parent() methods.

Or you could use a different selector.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the fiddle is you are selecting the imediate parent, though meanwhile the div that you want is 2 more levels higher. Switching that select to this does the job.

```
var x = $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('height');
```

This looks a little messy and unreliable (if you change your html to add more divs around the anchor tag, the javascript will select the wrong div again) so if you add a common class to the divs that you want the height to you can then select the specific parent. So lets say i added the class called "parentNeeded" to the divs "one" and "two", you can then use the following statement

```
var x = $(this).parents(".parentNeeded").css('height');
```

You can see this in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/K3dx5/5/